# How do I prove that $\lim _{x\to a}e^x = e^a$?

Tags: limits

I want to be able to do this without assuming that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$. I've tried to do this using both the delta-epsilon definition and the squeeze theorem, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: What definition of $e^x$ are you using? Or at least, which properties of the exponential can we assume known? Without this information, it's impossible to answer such a question properly.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is constant, note that
$$
\lim_{x \to a} e^x = e^a
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{x \to a} e^{x-a} = 1
$$
which is equivalent to $x-a \to 0$ since $e^x=1$ has only one solution...

Comment: So all I would have to do is prove that the limit as x approaches a of f(x) = the limit as x approaches 0 of f(x + a) and that the limit as x approaches 0 of e^x = 1?

Comment: @Logic that's one way to do it

Answer (score 0):

It is true by continuity, indeed note that by esponential properties

$$ \lim_{x \to a} e^x = \lim_{h\to 0} e^{h+a}=e^a\cdot \lim_{h\to 0} e^{h}=e^a\cdot1=e^a$$